# jQuery appending second class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a class called 'closable' and trying to add it an existing div. At the moment it appears to ignore it completely. :(

```
$(type).addClass('closable');
jQuery(form).append('<div class="'+type+'">'+data.msg+'</div>');
```

HTML output: doesn't actually show.

---

I have also tried:

```
jQuery(form).append('<div class="'+ type +' closable">'+data.msg+'</div>');
```

HTML output:

```
<div class="warning closable">No data given</div>
```

This 'looks' like it gives it the class but it doesn't actually trigger the JS that's related to it.

Neither of these options work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `type`?

Comment: What is `type`? You're first creating it as a jQuery object and adding a class to it, then appending it to a string? Also, what do you mean by `doesn't trigger the JS that's related to it`?

Comment: Please show us the code for your trigger. It needs to be a delegate.

Comment: type is either output as 'success' or 'warning' which is a seperate CSS class that create a orange/green box based on the type.

Comment: What is `form`?!? Should you not write `jQuery('form').append(...` instead?

Comment: Form is... a form believe it or not. With the way the codes written, that's not really possible. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type` in your case is an HTMLElement jQuery object, not a string.

If you want to use a string variable, than make sure it's one.

```
jQuery($ => {   // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

    const $form = $("#form");
    const type = "warning"; // warning // success //
    const data = { msg: "hello!" };

    $form.append(`<div class="${type}">${data.msg}</div>`);
    $(`.${type}`).addClass("closable");
});
```

Regarding your late edit: while dealing with dynamically generated elements be careful and delegate your event listeners using the `.on()` method `http://api.jquery/on/`:

```
$("#nonDynamicParentEl").on("click", ".dynamicEl", fn);
```

Comment: Appending a jQuery object to a string...? Really?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I hit POST too fast Rory. Happens to me too.

Comment: Obviously was an honest mistake - Us StackOverflow users are code vultures.. :')

Comment: My point was more that the OPs question is so vague that until he gives more details this is a complete guess at best. No offence intended.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan true! I'm completely guessing, drinking my coffee and hitting POST before doing all my edits, having fun and listening to Depeche. What a perfect day!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'll be honest, I'm a bit jealous :D

Comment: @TomDwyer while this *too chatty* comments are deprecated from StackOverflow version 0, it's still fun to be human sometimes :D

Comment: @TomDwyer we cannot in any case properly answer your Q while we still don't know what value is carried by your var `type` :)

Comment: I updated the OP with the triggering JS but as I said, type is simply output as either 'warning' or 'success' when it passes through an if.

It then gets either one of those two classes based on that.

Comment: @TomDwyer ok edited my answer to match your explanations and expectations ;D look at the last line of code to target the desired class + var And here's an example: http://jsbin.com/atIFokO/1/edit

Comment: So it was because of how the triggered JS was working... rewrote it and now it works.

Thank you! I would totally buy you a beer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on('click','.close_img', function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(600).remove();
    });
```

This was the magic that got it working.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `$(".element").on("click",function(){})` on dynamically added elements

Comment: This solution is incomplete. You need a "parent" element and then the "child" element which responds to events. Just like Arun suggested.

Comment: yes, sorry about that, i mixed them up, but this wil work in most cases 
$("body").on("click",".addedElement",function(){});

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood it is a problem with dynamic elements and event handling.

Your code `jQuery(form).append('<div class="'+ type +' closable">'+data.msg+'</div>');` looks fine, but it looks like the problem might be with associated js code

Since the element is added dynamically, you need to use event delegation based event handling, so instead of

```
$('.closable').click(function(){
    //do something
})
```

you need

```
$(document).on('click', '.closable', function(){
    //do something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery(form)
    .append('<div>'+data.msg+'</div>')
    .children().last()
    .addClass('closable')
;
```

or use the simpler solution by cars10 (currently in the comments).

Comment: Here you are adding class to the form, not the appended DIV

Comment: @roasted: thanks, i noticed after hitting enter ... corrected

Comment: Or you could do `.append($('<div>'+data.msg+'</div>').addClass('closable'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this like,

```
jQuery(function(){
    //other variables like form etc
    var type = 'warning';
    jQuery(form).append('<div class="'+type+'">'+data.msg+'</div>');

    // use . for class selectors and add below line after adding it in form
    jQuery('.'+type).addClass('closable');

    jQuery(document).on('click','.'+type,function(){
        //your code for type class
    });

});
```

To work for **dynamically created elements** use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: So this 'kind' of worked. It added the class to the element but again, it didn't trigger the associated JS.

Answer (score 0):

> type is either output as 'success' or 'warning' which is a seperate CSS class

Given that `type` is a string, what you have in your second example will work:

```
jQuery(form).append('<div class="' + type + '">' + data.msg + '</div>');
```

> This 'looks' like it gives it the class but it doesn't actually trigger the JS that's related to it.

I'm assuming you mean that events are not being attached to the dynamically appended element. This is because events are attached on load of the page, so you need to use a delegated event handler. Try this:

```
$(form).on('click', '.success', function() {
    // do something
});
```